# How to refractor the bunch of attrubute assignments in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I have below bunch of jQuery snippets, which use to assign the respective tooltip to particular field on click on the field,

```
$('#callerfirst').attr('title', 'May I have your first name?');
    $('#callerlast').attr('title', 'May I have your last name?');
    $('select[name="carriername"]').attr('title','May I have your wireless provider?');
    $('select[name="csrcallerrelationship"]').attr('title','May I have your relationship to the account holder?');
    $('#accountholder_firstname').attr('title','May I have the first name on the account?');
    $('#accountholder_lastname').attr('title','May I have the last name on the account?');
    $('input[name="contactphone"]').attr('title','May I have a phone number where you can be reached?');
    $('input[name="contactphone2"]').attr('title','May I have a phone number where you can be reached?');
    $('#email').attr('title','With your email address, we will send you an email confirming your claim and another from UPS with your tracking information.');
    $('input[name="address1"]').attr('title','May I have the address on the account?');
    $('select[name="cemake"]').attr('title','May I have the make of your phone?');
    $('select[name="cemodel"]').attr('title','May I have the model of your phone?');
    $('input[name="incidentdate"]').attr('title','May I please have the date on which the incident occured?');
    $('input[name="ccholdername"]').attr('title','May I have the name as it appears on the card?');
    $('input[name="ccmask"]').attr('title','May I have the card number?');
    $('input[name="cvvcode"]').attr('title','May I have the 3 or 4 digit CVV code on the back of the card?');
    $('input[name="billaddress1"]').attr('title','Please provide your billing address.');
    $('input[name="shipaddress1"]').attr('title','May I have the address you want the phone shipped to?');

//Trigger for activating Tooltips
    $('input[title]').tooltip();
    $('select[title]').tooltip({
        events: {
            widget:"focus,blur"
        }
    });

    $('.tooltip').livequery(function() {
        $(this).each(function() {
            $(this).bgiframe();
        });
    });
```

Now how can I refractor the above snippet for better optimization or simple words how to decrease the redundancy?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put the texts directly to `title` attribute of each input element in the markup.

Comment: @VisioN I editted the Question, sorry for incompleted question.. please read again

Comment: @Padyster Still, you should set attribute directly in HTML markup. Why couldn't you? BTW, these attributes values look static, so...

Comment: The tooltip msg goes to a popup

Comment: @Padyster But tooltip will use attribute title set in HTML, so why not set it directly in HTML??? And to answer your question, as no value is shared nor selector, how could you refactor it?!

Comment: isn't it a good practice to have it dynamically?

Comment: @Padyster If you are looking for optimization, then set it directly in HTML. You can generate it dynamically but server side. You shouldn't set it client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than moving the attributes into the HTML markup as the comments suggest, you could improve the code:

```
var dictionary = {
    '#callerfirst' : 'May I have your first name?',
    '#callerlast' : 'May I have your last name?',
    'select[name="carriername"]' : 'May I have your wireless provider?',
    'select[name="csrcallerrelationship"]' : 'May I have your relationship to the account holder?'
    ...
    ...
};

$.each(dictionary, function(key, value){
    $(key).attr('title', value);
});
```

The benefit of this is if you need to put the text elsewhere in the element other than the title attribute, it's one change instead of many. The `attr()` repetition is removed.